# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'password' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, local

```
def start():

    global smallq
    global medq
    global larq
    check = input("Would you like to change prices? Press Y to change or Press N to  continue to order: ")

    if check == "Y":
        password = input("What is the password?: ")
    else:
        print("Continuing to order...")
        smallq = 50
        medq = 120
        larq = 180
        order()

    if password == "please":
        quilt_price()
    else:
        print("Wrong password", "\n", "Continuing to order...")
        smallq = 50
        medq = 120
        larq = 180
        order()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/palerj09/Documents/SAC RW.py", line 128, in <module>
    start()
  File "/Users/palerj09/Documents/SAC RW.py", line 18, in start
    if password == "please":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'password' referenced before assignment
```

If I write "N" to answer the input it runs `order()` and everything works fine, except once `order()` has finished it brings up the error. I've tried making `password` global but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What if the input was not `"Y"`? Then `password` would never have been created, thus doing `if password == "please"` would raise an error. Perhaps do `password = None` before your conditional statements.

Comment: `password is None` is more pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
I haven't tried changing the input, but i did try the password = none before the conditionals. At then end of the code it repeated the statement else: print("Wrong password.. etc) and repeated the whole order() function again

Comment: @pynovice That's for comparison. We're defining a variable here

Comment: @Rasp Are you calling `start()` in your `order()`? I don't see how it could repeat

Comment: No i'm not, that's why I'm confused.

But i just figured it out, i just added a sys.exit() at the end of the order(). I have no idea why it didn't work otherwise, but it's working now so it's all good. 
Thanks for your help